# How can Internet Explorer render same source in different ways?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question might be too broad as I have no specific code to show the problem I have. Probably it's impossible anyway.

I am using Internet Explorer 11 to open a web page generated on some system. I take the page source, copy the content into a text-file, and replace any references to an external javascript file, stylesheet file etc. to a local directory. Then I make sure that the local directory contain the *exact* same javascript files, stylesheets etc.

When I now open the copied html source in two tabs of the *same* Internet Explorer browser, the contents are shown somewhat differently! I am pretty sure that no other files are included somewhere in the javascript, stylesheet, ... files. So how is it possible, that the same source can get rendered in different ways? Is there anything I can check or investigate?

Additional information:

- On the firefox browser the original and the copied page are shown exactly the same way, as far my eyes can tell.
- I have cleared the browser

If people think this question does not belong here, please suggest a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Is compatibility view on on one of the occasions? Tools - Compatibility view settings. Also are both running on same zone, IE. internet, local intranet, trusted sites etc?

Comment: Well, the two pages are shown in two tabs in the same browser instance.

Comment: does not matter, other tab can be in compatibility view and the other not, also they still can be in different zone.

Comment: @Esa: Ok I see. But it seems the compatibility view is deactivated for both tabs

Answer (score 1):

What gets lost when you save to a file and then open from that file are the HTTP headers. Specifically, the HTTP `Content-Type` header instructs the browser what kind of document to treat the data as. It may be that the server instructs the browser to treat the document as XHTML (hypothetically); but when you open the document by itself it's treated as pure HTML soup. This may trigger a difference in when Quirks Mode is used, which can lead to subtle or not-so-subtle differences. There may be other headers triggering the same or other things, but the problem and difference is pretty surely the lack of HTTP headers.

Comment: So how can I get/see those headers? I see one line I am using in both tabs: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.

Comment: Check the developer tools of the browser, and look at the HTTP request and response. I'm not too familiar with IE to tell you exactly where those are. But I'm talking about **HTTP headers**, not HTML header meta tags. Very different things!

Comment: The Content-type for the original page seems to be `Content-Type: text/html`. How can it help me to change the copied source, which I just load by using the 'File->Open' context of IE?

Comment: I honestly don't know or care in detail what triggers Quirks Mode in IE and what doesn't. It's simply a likely source of error. It may also be that some Javascript isn't loading due to cross-site scripting limitations only in effect when not serving from an actual web server. Try serving the site through an actual local web server which preferably emits the same headers too.